# Issue with Path using urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm trying to save an image using `urllib.urlretrieve` and I'm having some issues with specifying the pathname. When I make the call `urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, "C:\my_folder\test.jpg")` I get the error: `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\my_folder\test.jpg'`

I've tried escaping the backslashes as well by using C:\\my_folder\\test.jpg but that doesn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full code and stacktrace? Also, I assume you've validated that there is in face a file at that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\my_folder\test.jpg'
```

says you haven't got the escaping right. Note how it reports two slashes after the colon. The easiest way to get Windows paths correct is to use raw strings:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, r"C:\my_folder\test.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

try r"C:\my_folder\test.jpg" or "C:/my_folder/test.jpg", if you do not want to be escaped by "\" you could add r just at the front of your string which contains "\". Besides, '/' also works in windows, you could also use it.